How my digital camera creates itself this picture?
here is a picture produced by my digital camera

My camera is an (quite old) Panasonic DMC-FZ200.
My question is : what happened, and at which stage of the process the bug was?
Months ago, while hiking, I took my camera to take a picture. When I powered it on, it show that (see the link above) on the screen. At this time I had the protection cover on the lens, so no light can enter (or very few).
I have all the UI showed (aperture, speed etc.) and I was able to shoot the picture (it's why I get it :) ).
I didn't try other thing than mentioned (zoom, setting modification) because I took the picture and powered off the camera thinking that it just died. I removed the battery and starting up again, and everything was fine.
We can also see a lens effect, somebody says that we can see the "counter lens effect", because as the data entered were not from lens but from internal bug, there were not deformed by the lens, so the correction applied on un-deformed data, deformed it.
I should add that sometime, my zoom moves as it wants, and my controls on settings such as aperture, speed, gets stuck, but moving to another menus from the rotational selector (between program, film, speed priority, aperture priority etc.) still works and gives me back the control.
Thank you for your answers,
BinKiwi
ps : for your information I'm trying to find the right site to post my question.
